# How to save locally advertise from web pages?

Tags: javascript, java

I have an application to make to grab the advertise from different web sites.
One of them is:

http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/knifeskills/ss/corepepper.htm

http://imageshack.com/a/img922/706/2TdDgf.png

I need to grab the image, the link where it goes, the size of the image.

I need the application to be able to grab all google ads, all adchoises ads from the web page, maybe located at different locations in the web page
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
J

Comment: *Too Broad: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url= new URL("http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/knifeskills/ss/corepepper.htm");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

You probably want to save the inputLine. This should give you the data from the "inspect" option. It seems all the google ads have a data-google-query-id. So just filter those out and all the data you need is included in the div.

Comment: i already get the source code for the html, the problem was to interpret the advertises. Could you please explain how to get the image of the ad and details for it?